# Hide links and icon in checkout page

Tags: wordpress

I have this issue with Wordpress. I want hide menu links and menu icons in checkout page excluding personal logo. I added this code in my function.php, but only links hide:

```
<?php function ace_remove_checkout_nav_menu( $val, $args ) {
// Make sure 'primary' is set to the menu ID you'd like to hide
if ( is_checkout() && in_array( $args->theme_location, array( 'primary' ) ) ) {
    return false;
}

return $val; }add_filter( 'pre_wp_nav_menu', 'ace_remove_checkout_nav_menu', 10, 2 );
```

and this is the website's link: https://www.jpdavid.it

Comment: From the HTML code it doesn't seem like your header icons are part of the navigation menu so this code snippet won't affect them at all (as you already saw). You'll need to either use CSS to hide them or modify `header.php` so these are hidden when `is_checkout()` returns `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve in this way:

```
<?php
if ( is_checkout() ) {
  ?>
  <style>
    .theme-primary-menu, .header-action, .menu-toggle-btn {
      display: none !important;
    }
  </style>
  <?php
}
```

Thank to everyone.